# Pubspec.yaml Package upgrade issues

Tags: flutter, pubspec, flutter-upgrade

I just upgraded flutter to the latest version and just went through a bunhc of pub dev package upgrades to make everything work. The last error I am getting I cant seem to resolve though:

> Resolving dependencies... Because flutter_cache_manager 3.3.0 depends
> on http ^0.13.0 and no versions of flutter_cache_manager match >3.3.0
> <4.0.0, flutter_cache_manager ^3.3.0 requires http ^0.13.0. So,
> because dont_forget_the_spoon depends on both flutter_cache_manager
> ^3.3.0 and http ^1.0.0, version solving failed. exit code 1

I must be missing something but I think I am meeting all the requirements for packages so not sure I why I am getting this issue...

These are all my dependencies version in my pubspec.yaml:

```
 cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  google_sign_in: ^6.1.4
  firebase_core: ^2.2.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.1.2
  cloud_firestore: ^4.0.5
  firebase_analytics: ^10.0.5
  smooth_page_indicator: ^1.0.0+2
  dropdown_search: ^5.0.2
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  url_launcher: ^6.1.5
  purchases_flutter: ^4.2.2
  provider: ^6.0.3
  sign_in_with_apple: ^4.1.0
  app_tracking_transparency: ^2.0.2+4
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^5.0.5
  share_plus: ^7.0.2
  launch_review: ^3.0.1
  youtube_player_iframe: ^4.0.1
  firebase_storage: ^11.0.10
  image_picker: ^0.8.6+1
  transparent_image: ^2.0.0
  image_cropper: ^5.0.0
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.3
  in_app_review: ^2.0.6
  screenshot: ^2.1.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.14
  flutter_cache_manager: ^3.3.0
  http: ^1.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade http to a version compatible with flutter_cache_manager

```
http: ^0.13.4
```

Update flutter_cache_manager to a version compatible with http: ^0.13.4

```
flutter_cache_manager: ^3.3.0
```

Comment: Once I did that, I got this error:

Because dont_forget_the_spoon depends on flutter_cache_manager ^4.0.0 which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.

Comment: flutter_cache_manager: ^3.3.0

Comment: its like wack-a-mole:

So, because dont_forget_the_spoon depends on both image_cropper ^5.0.0 and http ^0.13.4, version solving failed.